# Crossing out an unmarked expired US Visa in my Indian Passport

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens

Is it fine to strike off Expired US Visas in an old Indian Passport? I have some US Visas which the consulate itself has marked CWOP[Cancelled Without Prejudice], while some of them as old as 2015 expiry are not marked off. This creates confusion sometimes at the airlines when they take time to find the valid(unexpired Visa). This is in a Expired Indian Passport with one Valid Visa. I have a new Passport which is never used as the old one just expired.

Comment: What do you mean by "mark off" and "strike off"?

Comment: I meant draw a line across it diagonally to indicate its expired. With a pencil just to be safe I guess.

Comment: I think this is probably a bad idea. Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/will-doodling-on-my-passport-make-it-invalid

Comment: @Traveller. Understood. But in my case the Passport is already expired but has one Valid Visa and I have since procured a new Passport which is empty.

Comment: You still have to proffer the expired passport in order to use the still-valid visa that it contains. Marking in that expired passport could cause rejection, as described in Traveller's citation above. I wouldn't take that chance.

Comment: @David, I thought it only applies to valid passports. Expired/Damaged passports with valid visas are accepted assuming the damage is minimal.

Comment: Sure...maybe. But why would you take any chances here? Is there enough satisfaction to be gained by drawing a line over old visas to overbalance the risk? Not for me, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In general it's never a good idea to modify a visa stamp in any way, even in an expired passport if it still has other valid visas in it.

Until recently I had a similar situation (although in my current passport, not an old one) - I had one visa that expired in 2018, and a second that was current and expires in 2020.

After causing confusion as you've described more than once, recently an immigration officer circled the Expiration Date on the expired visa.  This makes is far more obvious that this visa is expired when looking at it.

I don't know if this is an official/standard action or not, but in my case it was done by a US immigration officer, and has been seen by other US immigration staff as well as US consulate staff (when applying for a new visa a few months ago) and neither have commented on it so I'm sure it wouldn't be an issue for you to do the same thing yourself.

Answer (score 2):

My wife has several cancelled US visas in her passport.  One expired without being cancelled.  A US immigration officer once circled the expiration date with a ball point pen.  If you were to do that, I doubt anyone would know that you yourself had done it.

Another thing, you might consider, however, is simply presenting the passport open to the page with the valid visa, whenever you give it to someone who needs to find that visa (i.e., a US immigration officer or an airline ground agent when you're on your way to the US).  Also memorize the page number so if anyone ever looks at an invalid visa, you can say "the valid one is on page 17" (or wherever it is).

Comment: A variant of this approach is to put an easily removed marker such as a Post-it note or paperclip on the page with the valid visa, but present the passport open at the photo and signature page.